# finding last child div in nested fieldset

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

Within a jquery mobile page I have a page with a nested fieldset.
I need to dynamically add an input and button field anytime a certain button is clicked.
My first step has been trying to find the id of the last dynamically added control group.
That is where I am stuck. 
I have tried a lot of different ways to get to the div but haven't had any luck so I was hoping I could get some help from the experts.

My latest attempt...

```
  $('#ServicePage #ServiceArticle #ServiceList #collapse #btnaddOther').on('click', function () {
     var ct = $('#ServicePage #ServiceArticle #ServiceList  #collapse');
     getLastId(ct);
  });

  function getLastId(ct) {
    var id = $(ct.last).attr('id');
    addOtherItem(id);
  }
```

Below is an example of the page.  The div i'm trying to reach is below the 2nd fieldset and has an id of collapse.  I need to get the last child div within the collapse div i.e. I need to return the id= addOther_1.
I hope that makes sense.

```
    <div id="ServicePage" data-role="page" class="ui-page-theme-a">
    <article id="ServiceArticle" data-role="content" class="ui-content">
        <form>
            <br />
            <div id="ServiceList" class="ui-corner-all custom-corners">
                <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-b">
                    <h3>Color Services</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-body ui-body-a">
                    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                        <legend>Select Color Services</legend>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="service" id="serviceHiLight" value="HiLight" />
                        <label for="serviceHiLight">Highlights</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="service" id="serviceLoLight" value="LoLight" />
                        <label for="serviceLoLight">Low-Lights</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="service" id="serviceRetouch" value="Retouch" />
                        <label for="serviceRetouch">Retouch</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="service" id="serviceHiLightRetouch" value="HiLightRetouch" />
                        <label for="serviceHiLightRetouch">Highlight Retouch</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="service" id="servicePainting" value="Painting" />
                        <label for="servicePainting">Painting like Ombre or Balayage</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="service" id="serviceAllOver" value="AllOver" />
                        <label for="serviceAllOver">All over color</label>
                        *<fieldset data-role="collapsible">
                            <legend>Other</legend>
                            <div id="collapse" data-role="controlgroup">
                                <div id="addOther_1" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
                                    <input id="txtaddOther_1" type="text" name="service" data-wrapper-class="controlgroup-textinput ui-btn" placeholder="Enter Service Name" />
                                    <button id="btnDeleteOther_1" style="background-color: transparent; border-style: none;" class="ui-btn-b ui-shadow ui-btn ui-icon-delete ui-btn-inline ui-btn-icon-notext ui-corner-all">Delete</button>
                                </div>
                                <a id="btnaddOther" href="#" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-plus">Add</a>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </article>
</div>
```

How would I go about accessing this nested div?

Thanks

Comment: Since it has an ID just use that `$('#collapse')` since by defintion ID's are unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function getLastId() {
    var $x = $('fieldset:last-of-type > div:first-of-type > div:first-of-type')
    // addOtherItem($x.attr("id"));
    // Just to show we got the id, I am putting it in a div.
    // Remove when done and un-comment line 3
    $('#tmpDiv').html($x.attr("id"))
  }

$('#btn').on('click', function(){
  getLastId();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- TMP -->
<div id="tmpDiv"></div>
<button id="btn">Click Me</button>
<!-- / TMP -->
<div id="ServicePage" data-role="page" class="ui-page-theme-a">
    <article id="ServiceArticle" data-role="content" class="ui-content">
        <form>
            <br />
            <div id="ServiceList" class="ui-corner-all custom-corners">
                <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-b">
                    <h3>Color Services</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-body ui-body-a">
                    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                        <legend>Select Color Services</legend>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="service" id="serviceHiLight" value="HiLight" />
                        <label for="serviceHiLight">Highlights</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="service" id="serviceLoLight" value="LoLight" />
                        <label for="serviceLoLight">Low-Lights</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="service" id="serviceRetouch" value="Retouch" />
                        <label for="serviceRetouch">Retouch</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="service" id="serviceHiLightRetouch" value="HiLightRetouch" />
                        <label for="serviceHiLightRetouch">Highlight Retouch</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="service" id="servicePainting" value="Painting" />
                        <label for="servicePainting">Painting like Ombre or Balayage</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="service" id="serviceAllOver" value="AllOver" />
                        <label for="serviceAllOver">All over color</label>
                        *<fieldset data-role="collapsible">
                            <legend>Other</legend>
                            <div id="collapse" data-role="controlgroup">
                                <div id="addOther_1" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
                                    <input id="txtaddOther_1" type="text" name="service" data-wrapper-class="controlgroup-textinput ui-btn" placeholder="Enter Service Name" />
                                    <button id="btnDeleteOther_1" style="background-color: transparent; border-style: none;" class="ui-btn-b ui-shadow ui-btn ui-icon-delete ui-btn-inline ui-btn-icon-notext ui-corner-all">Delete</button>
                                </div>
                                <a id="btnaddOther" href="#" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-plus">Add</a>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </article>
</div>
```

I like the "last-of-type" and "first-of-type" selectors

```
$('fieldset:last-of-type > div:first-of-type > div:first-of-type')
```

http://api.jquery.com/last-of-type-selector/

The above will select the last fieldset, then the first direct child div, then the first div after that (which is the one you want).

Comment: I tried 

$('#ServicePage fieldset:last-of-type #btnaddOther').on('click', function () {
        var ct = $('#ServicePage fieldset:last-of-type > div:first-of-type').attr('id');
    getLastId(ct);
    });

Comment: Take a look at my code snippet. You are missing a "> div:first-of-type" and, why are you passing the ID to the function that is meant to retrieve it?

Comment: I am passing the id of the page because there are multiple jquery mobile pages in one htnl page.  A lot of these pages have divs with fieldsets.  I need to target a specific page.  I will try again.  Thanks

Comment: I tried $addOther = $('#ServicePage fieldset:last-of-type > div:first-of-type > div:first-of-type') and it can't be found.

Comment: I knew you would get it. You can always just add a #divId to make any selector a compound selector. #div > selectAnythingInsideDiv  > repeat. Glad it helped!! :D

Answer (score 0):

Why not keep track of the last one using an id.. For example: id = 'LastOne', now, when you add a new item, remove the attribute from the actual last one, and then just place it on the one you're about to add. Basically, something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.add').click(function(){
        var nvar = $('#lo').removeAttr('id').clone();
        nvar.attr('id','lo');
        nvar.insertAfter($('.mydiv').last());
    });
});
```

You click on an ADD button (with the class .add) and then it looks for the LasOne (LO for short), removes it attr, makes a clone of it and then places it below the last one. Of course, you can also remove the attr AFTER you insert. That way, you wouldn't need to use "LAST".. since you don't really know what the last one is.

Check the fiddle working here: http://jsfiddle.net/lrojas94/v26fk8yd/

Comment: I have to loop through all the added text/button combos and use them later in calculations.  The app is like a wizard and user needs to be able to navigate back and see all entries. I have a small procedure that assigns a new id by adding 1 to the id.  ie addOrder_1, the new one would be addOrder_2.

Comment: Then you can just loop using jquery each. Just do: $('.mydiv').each(function(index,elem){//do something}); You can do it after or before inserting a new item, depending on your needs.

Comment: What I really need to know is how can I access the last divs id

Comment: ids are unique... So if you keep your last ones IDed then it should be easy. Also, you could add a class LASTONE to all last divs. That way you should have access to all them by using the select '.lastone'

Answer (score 0):

I was making this wayyyyy to difficult.  I got the answer by trying something that charlietfl said "Since it has an ID just use that $('#collapse') since by definition ID's are unique –  charlietfl"
Because I am using jquery mobile I did have to include the page name so it was simply

```
$addOther = $('#ServicePage #collapse');
```

The name of the jquery mobile page and the id of the div I need to look into.

Thanks everyone for your help.

I forgot to add how I found the last div within that div...

```
$('#ServicePage #collapse').find('.a').last();
```

This found the last div withing a div.  The div I would looking in has the id #collapse.